# Como abrir popup dando clic en alguna de la opciones de un select

Tags: javascript, html

tengo dos popup en mi html, el primero lo abro usando un `<a href=""></a>` usando en JS addEventListener()

```
openPopup.addEventListener('click', function() {
  overlay.classList.add('active');
]);
```

me abre sin problemas, pero el 2do popup necesito abrirlo desde un option en un select:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required="required">
        <option value="">Asunto:</option>
        <option value="">Reporte de daño</option>
        <option value="">Luminaria robada</option>
        <option value="">Solicitud para instalaciones</option>
        <option class="openPopupPqrs" id="openPopupPqrs" value="">PQRS</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

usando esta función:

```
openPopupPqrs.addEventListener('click', function() {
  overlayPqrs.classList.add('active');
  console.log("Hola entrando a PQRS");
});
```

pero no entra a la función cuando doy click, y el navegador me da un error de Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'), pense que iba a servirme pero parece que no.

Comment: ¿Dónde estás definiendo a la variable `openPopupPqrs`? Prestale atención al mensaje de error que da :)

Comment: La variable la estoy declarando en el JS, se me olvido colocarla, esta asi:
var openPopupPqrs = document.getElementById('openPopupPqrs'); Sorry :D

Comment: Asegurate que openPopupPqrs este definido dentro de tu funcion, tal vez esta definida pero no para esa funcion. Te esta diciendo que el valor de openPopupPqrs es NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te propongo la siguiente solución, en vez de intentar aplicar un Listener al option, le pones uno al **Select** y validas cuál fue el **option** seleccionado:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required="required">
        <option value="">Asunto:</option>
        <option value="">Reporte de daño</option>
        <option value="">Luminaria robada</option>
        <option value="">Solicitud para instalaciones</option>
        <option value="openPopupPqrs">PQRS</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Con el atributo **value** en el option, puedes identificar cuál seleccionó, y a nivel de JS:

```
const select = document.getElementById('subject');
select.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    if (this.value === 'openPopupPqrs') {
        overlayPqrs.classList.add('active');
        console.log("Hola entrando a PQRS");
    }
});
```

Comment: Gracias <3 si sirvio, pero quisiera saber porque no pudo hacerse con le option? el Event se comporta de forma diferente depende al objeto y vi que cambiaste el 'click' por 'change'.

Comment: Tengo entendido que cuando haces clic sobre alguna de las opciones del **select**, realmente estás es haciendo un evento click sobre el select, puedes probar esta cambiando el change por click, y verás que cada vez que seleccionas una opción, realmente el click actual sobre el select y no el option.